# How to generate temporary API keys with Symfony 4

Tags: php, api, symfony, symfony4

To give a bit of background - I currently have an API in place, but I want my mobile app to be able to communicate with it. I looked at the following link to setup authentication for that. It goes into how I can authenticate a client (mobile in this case), if they pass an API key - the problem is that it doesn't get into how the key actually gets created.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html

Ideally, I'd like the mobile app to offer the user a chance to login (username/password), and after they login the API would generate an API key, which the user would use for all subsequent requests.

Anyone done this yet with Symfony 4?

Comment: Have you just described oauth(2)?

Comment: I wasn't really thinking about oauth, because I thought that's more relevant for giving permission to 3rd party apps to access an API on your behalf. I suppose that could work in this case, as the mobile client would act as the '3rd party app'. I was hoping for something more simple though - I just want a straight forward login into the API system, since I control both ends (no 3rd party apps or services involved). Would you still recommend oauth in this scenario?

Comment: Just did some more reading - looks like oauth would be the best option here. I'll revise the question.

Comment: The details of getUserByApiKey is up to you to implement. The easiest way would be to create another table where each user will be linked to such a key by its ID and look in there if key exists and is valid. Key can be created in required format and checked for uiniqueness in that table using it as primary key or manually by doing select on it. To generate actual key you can use UUID or uniq function variants. I’ve done this using Laravel and Sentinel provider, but by reading the docs can see they are very similar in approach.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov - what about the actual login piece? Would I just use the existing `/login` path, to login, and post the username/password from the mobile device? The other question, would be how to tell the Symfony security component to return the API key after the successful login (assuming I create/store the key in the User table)

Comment: It's sounding like I just have to build this out. Guess I was wondering if some of this functionality already existed in Symfony. Based on all the digging/reading I've done, it's not looking like it.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing it all together. The API key works as a substitute for username/password. You should not make mixed returns of same function as it creates uncertainty - if your login function in API returns authorization token based on either API key or username/password, then let it do so, and nothing else.

Read part 3 - it essentially describes how to simulate session in API environment where no cookies are present. The authentication token in API = session cookie in web, you will have to store it yourself as there's no session in API. Most of the functionality is there, you have to fill the blanks in the documentation where it tells you to.

Comment: I understand the whole premise behind the API key, and how simulate session, etc. What I'm trying to understand is the initial login (which would generate/acquire the API key). Currently the only client using the API is a Vue app, which is running locally - users login using the traditional login form, and the Vue app is able to utilize the session, so no need for API key.

Comment: My question in the other comment was if I can just leverage the existing `/login` path (in the mobile app), and post the username/password (for the initial request), to get the API key, and any subsequent requests would use that API key for requesting data.

Comment: So I understand that the API key is a substitute for username/password; but there has to be an initial login to gain that API key. Once the mobile app has the API key, it can store it for all requests for as long as it is valid. If it ever loses validity, the mobile app would have the user login again to get a renewed API key.

Comment: Indeed so, for that there's usually a personal cabinet user logs into for the very first time. It would be possible to send an e-mail with newly created API key to the user, but having it returned after initial login is... unwise.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking for a solution specific for Symfony 4. I can totally do an out of the box solution, where I have a custom login point; but I want to do it with the built in Symfony security framework.

Comment: I think I will be able to do what I need to do using the following - https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html